# How to use jQuery to change img src?

Tags: html, jquery, css, treeview

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="treeview" onclick="changeImgFolder('rootFolder')" id="rootFolder">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />  <span>Content 1</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li id="folder001">
                <a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />SubFolder</a>
            </li>
            <li id="folder002">
                <a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />  Level One</a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li id="folder004"><a><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />  Level Two</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />  Level Two </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li id="folder005"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />  Level Three</a></li>
                            <li id="folder006"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" />  Level Three</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="folder003"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level One</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I create a multilevel sidebar. I add an id on each `li` element. I want to change `img src` when I click in `li` element. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

use like it

```
$(document).on('click', '.sidebar-menu li', function (e) {
  let Img = e.target.children[0];
    Img.src = 'newImageURL';
});
```

---

In this case, there are nested li elements and when you click on inner li items it triggers the same click to parent ul li and it changes all occurrence of parent li
so we use vanilla JS code to overcome this issue

Comment: thanks for answer but if using it. it will change all img src in children element click. i want to change just one element clicked .

Comment: did you test it, ```$(this)``` belongs to clicked items not all li items?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `each()` method, which defines a specific clickable item for an `img` tag.

Was such a result necessary?

```js
$('.sidebar-menu * img').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', function() {   
    $(this).attr('src', 'https://st2.depositphotos.com/5266903/8135/v/600/depositphotos_81358350-stock-illustration-client-flat-icon.jpg');   
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar-menu * img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li class="treeview" id="rootFolder">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> <span>Content 1</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li id="folder001"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> SubFolder</a>
      </li>
      <li id="folder002">
        <a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level One</a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li id="folder004"><a><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level Two</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level Two </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li id="folder005"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level
                  Three</a></li>
              <li id="folder006"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level
                  Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="folder003"><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/img/ico_folder_off.png" alt="Folder Image" /> Level One</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```